# Visual Studio 2013 expanding #pragma regions by itself

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

This problem is starting to irk me...I have a lot of code in a file, and I used `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion` so that I can easily navigate through the project. My problem is, sometimes when I start typing into one region, visual studio randomly opens another region (which is annoying because I lose focus on where I was typing). There must be a option somewhere to stop automatic expansion of regions, but I haven't found it. Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Ok idk why someone down voted this...I have been researching through google to find the answer and have been unsuccessful...

Comment: +1 because this is an IDE issue and I know what it's like not to get help with IDE related problems. Please provide some screenshots to show the problem in action for those who might not understand.

Comment: Hmm, haven't heard of this one before.  When you have odd problems like this that should irk a *lot* more devs then it is usually a good strategy to disable add-ins one-by-one.

Comment: @Axoren, its hard to capture a screen shot the problem is intermittent. I'll have collapsed region above a particular region I am working in, and I'll start typing some lines (either code or comments) and randomly the region above will expand. 
I was hoping there would be a option to disable visual studio from expanding a region itself (only expand when I click the + mark).
I have one theory that I am currently testing, I believe my mouse was located above the region I was working in, so maybe visual studio noticed the mouse hoovering over a collapsed region and decided to open the region

Comment: @HansPassant I have one add on, the Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2013. I need it to use code that was written for an adapter, I guess I could try removing it to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: That is not an add-in.  Don't remove it.

Comment: @HansPassant ah yes correct, I have no add ons and I only added that library. I am currently resetting my setting to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Restoring the settings did not fix the problem, I went to type a comment in and it expanded two regions above the region I was working it. I feel like it may be due to my mouse hoovering over the regions, because it expanded the region my mouse hoovered on and the region directly below it when I began to type the comment